# Whenever X is true do X, otherwise Y

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, operators, comparator

Think I'm brain dead. I need a really concise way of writing when X exists (the value for a specified key in a hash), print that value (i.e., X), otherwise, print 0. The reason it needs to be concise is because I'm using it in a `options` for a `form_tag`, and I'd like to avoid writing a method.

Can't think this through... here's what I've tried:

1. This won't work because it will always return "0": `<%= number_field_tag "transaction[][#{thing}]", :quantity, min: 0, placeholder: 0 || @transactionparams["#{thing}"] %>`
2. This won't work because whenever `@transactionparams` doesn't exist,  instead of getting 0, I get an error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`<%= number_field_tag "transaction[][#{thing}]", :quantity, min: 0, placeholder: @transactionparams["#{thing}"] %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a ternary operator?

```
@transactionparams = {:thing => "foo"}
puts @transactionparams ? @transactionparams[:thing] : 0
@transactionparams = nil 
puts @transactionparams ? @transactionparams[:thing] : 0
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Ruby 2+, you can take advantage of the fact that `nil.to_h` is an empty Hash:

```
v = @transactionparams.to_h[:thing] || 0
```

You can also take advantage of `nil.to_i` being zero:

```
v = @transactionparams.to_h[:thing].to_i
```

Note that Rails will patch `NilClass#to_h` to return an empty Hash too so this will work even if you're not in Ruby 2+.

These assume that you're not expecting `nil` to be a value in the Hash. If you want to allow `nil` values through then use [`fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) with a second argument:

```
v = @transactionparams.to_h.fetch(:thing, 0)
```

Since you're in Rails, you could throw a [`try`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) into the mix to swallow up the `nil` values of the instance variable:

```
v = @transactionparams.try(:fetch, :thing, 0).to_i
```

The trailing `to_i` call is there because `nil.try(m)` is `nil` for all `m`. You could also call `#[]` explicitly and avoid the second "return this instead of raising an exception" argument to `Hash#fetch`:

```
v = @transactionparams.try(:[], :thing).to_i
```

You can mix and match the above depending on what sorts of values you expect to have in `@transactionparams` and how specifically you need to handle `nil`s. I'd probably go with `to_h` and `to_i` in most cases:

```
@transactionparams.to_h[:thing].to_i
```

I tend to use `.to_X` methods (`#to_a` in particular) to hide `nil` checks all the time so I would immediately recognize the purpose of `to_h` and `to_i` in that expression.

Comment: This is a great other way of doing it. Good tip! I'll go with @kreek's answer because the code there reads more logically to my brain... I'll immediately understand intent, whereas this one, because it relies on one of Ruby's tricks, I'd have to think about. Thanks though!

Comment: No worries. Like I said, I use this sort of approach all the time so it is second nature to me.